# Android animation like jelly

Tags: android, android-animation

I am looking for image animation like jelly in android. As I am newbie please suggest me good code or link that can help me!!!

Thanks
Pravin Dodia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use box2d physics library which is integrated in [libgdx](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/) framework.